# Find root of a function with $\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ in a given interval

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, roots

I have defined a function with $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ expressions in it. So since this is a periodic function I know I have more than one root. The target is to find a solution for the second (or more general) the highest root in the given interval with my C++ code.

The function looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see in the picture in a given interval of [0,$\pi$] I have two roots. Only this interval is relevant for me.

Since I failed to receive the right solution with the Newton Method I choosed the Bisection Method because I than can be sure to receive a solution within the given interval. Newton Method also gave me solutions outside the interval which is not allowed here.

But here comes the problem. Since I have more than one root in this given interval there is no guarantee that I receive the right solution. I'm only interested in the **highest** root value. Currently I repeat the call of the function which calculates the root according to the bisection method several times until I don't receive a solution anymore. Everytime I define as lower bound the already found root (+very small increment) and the upper bound $\pi$.

It works of course but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way or a more common way to make sure to always receive the **highest** value of the root.

Has anybody an idea or a hint for a better solution?

Best regards
mk3

Comment: Hi, sorry but this is not true. Starting value of 1.5 will give me a solution outside my interval. Also the diagram is just an example the function will always look like this but with different values so there is not a certain start value which would be the best. Also I can use bisection method with more than one root as I already described. I just don't know if there is a more elegant way than I do it.

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly detected the values at 1 and 1.5 (I was first thinking of $\pi/2,$ but it seems the function is not defined there.

Comment: Could you post the function ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't. It is in a big project and has many dependencies in it so I think it would take around hours to descripe it easily. You answer already gave me the right solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to bracket the solution, I suggest you use subroutine *RTSAFE* from [*Numerical Recipes*](http://s3.amazonaws.com/nrbook.com/book_C210.html) (this is the $C$ version) (look at page $366$).  Quoting the book

*"The hybrid algorithm takes a bisection step whenever Newton-Raphson
would take the solution out of bounds, or whenever Newton-Raphson is not reducing
the size of the brackets rapidly enough"*.

Looking at your plots, in order to bracket the solution, what I should to is to find the maximum value of the function (solving $f'(x)=0$ - hoping that there is only one root in the interval). So, the largest root is between this point and the right bound.

If it is possible, I would enjoy playing with your function.

Comment: Hi, this answer is already enough for me. Your suggestion to find the maximum in the interval at first and then to use this as the new interval gave me already the right solution. Thank you so much for this. :)

Comment: @mk3. Yes but start from the right at a point where the function is negative. Since $f''(x)<0$ then, by Darboux theorem, Newton method will converge nicely without any overshoot of the solution. So, you can totally discard bisection.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following. It is simple, but it will work. Divide your interval in let say 1000 points and find both solutions with accuracy ~0.001 (or more if needed). In one dimension it is not a big deal. Then use these values as starting points for the Newton-Raphson and it will surely converge.

Comment: Hi, in my eyes it is even more unefficent than my current solution but thanks.

Comment: If you find two separate intervals (if you are sure that they are only two), which contain both solutions, you can also further continue with the Golden section search or with the Quadratic fit line search method. And then in the latest stage with the Newton-Raphson to recover full precision.